# Anything prevents optimizing tail-recursion?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, tail-recursion, knapsack-problem

I'm solving a knapsack problem in Haskell using Dynamic Programing. My first attempt was to build a two-dimensional table. But the memory easily gets blown up when the input is large(e.g. a 100 * 3190802 table).

Knowing that any given row `i` only depends on the row `(i - 1)`, I instead write a function in the hope to take the advantage of tail recursion:

```
import Data.Vector (Vector, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector as V

-- n items, k capacity, vs values, ws weights
ans:: Int -> Int -> Vector Int -> Vector Int -> Int
ans n k vs ws =
    let row = initRow k vs ws
    in  row ! k

initRow :: Int -> Vector Int -> Vector Int -> Vector Int
initRow k vs ws = itbl 1 $ V.replicate (k + 1) 0
    where n = V.length vs
          itbl i row
             | i > n = row
             | otherwise = itbl (i + 1) $ V.generate (k + 1) gen
             where gen w =
                       let w_i = ws ! (i - 1)
                           no_i = row ! w
                           ok_i = row ! (w - w_i) + (vs ! (i - 1))
                       in
                           if w < w_i then no_i
                           else max no_i ok_i
```

As shown in the code, `itbl` calls itself recursively and no further computation is made on its return value. However, I still see memory grow relentlessly in `top`:

```
 VIRT   PID USER      PR  NI  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1214m  9878 root      20   0 424m 1028 S  40.8 85.6   0:16.80 ghc
```

Is there anything in the code that prevents the compiler to produce optimized code for tail recursion?

[code](http://hpaste.org/90515)
[data](http://hpaste.org/90516)

--

Comment: Out of curiosity, try to remove the `$` operator from the `itbl (i + 1) $ V.generate (k + 1) gen` call so that it looks like so: `itbl (i + 1) (V.generate (k + 1) gen)`. My guess is that the `$` makes the call not be tail recursive.

Comment: Thanks you. But removing `$` doesn't seem to help. The memory usage still keeps growing.

Comment: I'd guess this is a problem with laziness.  Being tail recursive isn't enough (nor always desirable) in a lazy language.

Comment: Try replacing the `$` by `$!`.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing the right way. Yes, it's about strictness.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a strictness problem. The call to `generate` in

```
             | otherwise = itbl (i + 1) $ V.generate (k + 1) gen
```

does not actually force the vector into memory.

You can either `import Control.DeepSeq` and replace `$` by deeply strict application `$!!`:

```
             | otherwise = itbl (i + 1) $!! V.generate (k + 1) gen
```

or you can use an unboxed vector (which is probably faster) instead, by changing the import statements to

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed (Vector, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
```

(and leaving everything else as in your original program).